"Aw snap" error on chrome when running it in a docker container using puppeteer
enter image description hereI have an application that web browses to a URL and live streams the output using FFMPEG RTMP.
It is a docker container.
After about 2 hours into the container running google chrome on a URL gets an aw snap error.
unfortunately i have not written this code and i am not aware of what to do to fix it.
So far from my research i understand it can be the cache memory that is filling up and causing chrome to crash
I believe this is the main app file
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer-extra';
import { launch, getStream } from "puppeteer-stream";
import { URL } from 'node:url';
// add stealth plugin and use defaults (all evasion techniques)
import StealthPlugin from 'puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth';
import {startStream, stopStream} from './app-scripts/rtmp-streaming.mjs';
import {startSocat} from './app-scripts/socat-inspector.mjs';
import {generic_webpage} from './app-scripts/generic.mjs';
import { readFileSync } from 'node:fs';

const SCREEN_RESOLUTION = process.env.SCREEN_RESOLUTION;// '1280x720' //'1920x1080';
const [SCREEN_W,SCREEN_H] = SCREEN_RESOLUTION.split('x');
const RTMP_URL = process.env.RTMP_URL || '';
const [rtmpRawUrl, rtmpSource] = RTMP_URL?.split('|');
const streamingConfiguration = {
  RTMP_URL:rtmpRawUrl,
  RTMP_SOURCE:rtmpSource || 'C',
  SCREEN_RESOLUTION,
  DISPLAY: process.env.DISPLAY,
  VIDEO_FRAMERATE:30,
  VIDEO_BITRATE:10000,
  VIDEO_GOP:60,
  AUDIO_BITRATE:'160k',
  AUDIO_SAMPLERATE:48000,
  AUDIO_CHANNELS:2
};

const preloadFile = readFileSync('./preload.js', 'utf8');
    

const appReady = async (readyMessage, browser)=>{
  const page = (await browser.pages())[0];
  console.log('got page, ready to stream');
  startStream(streamingConfiguration, page);
  console.log(readyMessage);  
}
const microphoneNameFromKey= (key)=> {
  if(!key) return 'VirtualCableB_Microphone';
  if(key.length===1) return `VirtualCable${key}_Microphone`;
  return key;
}
const speakerNameFromKey= (key)=> {
  if(!key) return 'VirtualCableA_Speaker';
  if(key.length===1) return `VirtualCable${key}_Speaker`;
  return key;
}
const cameraNameFromKey= (key)=> {
  if(!key) return 'VirtualCableA_Camera';
  if(key.length===1) return `VirtualCable${key}_Camera`;
  return key;
}
await (async () => {
  if(!process.env.BROWSER_URL){
    console.log('Exitting, must specify source URL')
    return;
  }
  puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());
  const appUrls = [];
  if(process.env.BROWSER_URL){
    appUrls.push(process.env.BROWSER_URL);
  }
  if(process.env.BROWSER2_URL){
    appUrls.push(process.env.BROWSER2_URL);
  }
  if(process.env.BROWSER3_URL){
    appUrls.push(process.env.BROWSER3_URL);
  }
  const apps = [];
  appUrls.forEach((appUrl)=>{
    const [rawurl,appHandlerName,microphone,speaker,camera]=appUrl.split('|');
    console.log(`adding browser1 using index ${apps.length}`);
    startSocat(23222+apps.length,21222+apps.length)
    const url = new URL(rawurl);
    
    apps.push({
      inspectorPort:21222+apps.length,
      url,
      auth:process.env[`SITE_AUTH_${url.host.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g,'_')}`] || ':',
      SCREEN_W,
      SCREEN_H,
      SCREEN_X:SCREEN_W*apps.length,
      appHandlerName: appHandlerName || url.host.replace(/\./g,'-'),
      participantName : process.env.MEETING_PARTICIPANT_NAME || 'AWS Bot',
      microphone:microphoneNameFromKey(microphone),
      speaker:speakerNameFromKey(speaker),
      camera:cameraNameFromKey(camera)
    });
  })
  
  const appPromises = [];
  
  for (let index = 0; index < apps.length; index++) {
    const app = apps[index];
    
    const browser = await launch({
      headless: false,
      defaultViewport: null,
      ignoreHTTPSErrors: true, //TODO : Make this an option
      protocolTimeout: 0,
      executablePath: '/usr/bin/google-chrome',
      ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--enable-automation'],
      args: [
        '--kiosk',
        '--no-sandbox', 
        '--disable-gpu',
        // '--disable-extensions',
        `--window-size=${app.SCREEN_W},${app.SCREEN_H}`,
        `--window-position=${app.SCREEN_X},0`,
        '--no-first-run',
        '--no-default-browser-check',
        `--remote-debugging-port=${app.inspectorPort}`,
        '--remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0',
        '--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream',
        '--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required',
        '--auto-select-desktop-capture-source=Entire screen'
      ],
      port:app.inspectorPort
    });
    const page = (await browser.pages())[0];
    page.evaluateOnNewDocument(preloadFile);
    
    try{
      console.log(`running app ${JSON.stringify(app)}`);
      let {default:dynamicSiteHandler} = await import(`./app-scripts/${app.appHandlerName}.mjs`);
      appPromises.push(dynamicSiteHandler(browser,app,async (msg)=>{appReady(msg,browser)}));     
    }
    catch(err)
    {
      console.log(`Missing app for host ${app.appHandlerName}, using generic app handler : ${err.message}`);
      appPromises.push(generic_webpage(browser,app,async (msg)=>{appReady(msg,browser)}));     
    }
  }
  await Promise.all(appPromises).then(results=>{
    console.log('All apps exited');
    stopStream();
  }).catch(err=>{
    console.error(err);
  });
  process.exit(0);
  
})();

unfortunately i have not written this code and i am not aware of what to do to fix it. 
So far from my research i understand it can be the cache memory that is filling up and causing chrome to crash 


Try minimizing your code. Run it again, but remove some functionality. If it crashes, remove more functionality until it doesn't crash. Then you've just isolated the problem--the last thing you removed was probably causing the bug. You then have a [mcve] wherein the problem will either be obvious, or the question will be a lot more refined. Ideally, try to speed it up too so the failing operation happens sooner. Also, I suggest describing what this code does so there's some context. There are certainly some antipatterns in here and promise mismanagement, so it could be a simple code bug.

What is in preload.js and all these other imports like './app-scripts/rtmp-streaming.mjs'?

@ggorlen this comes from the github repo - https://github.com/amarmashruwala/browser-in-a-box/tree/main/browser-in-a-box

Kindly reduce the f••k out of this so we can help you

How much RAM does docker get? Try doubling it.
